# Weird JavaScript bug(?) in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I'm seeing an error with this code:

```
$('#foo').text(({rnd:((Math.random())>>0)}).rnd)
```

[(Live copy)](http://jsfiddle.net/csJVw/)

In `Safari 5.0 (5533.16)`, that very specific example shows a floating point number. Every other browser I've tested shows a zero (`0`).

My two questions are:

1. Can you test this in whatever version of safari you have and tell me if it shows a zero or a random number.
2. Anyone have any idea what could possibly be causing this?

My thoughts are that the `>>` is being somehow interpreted as `(>)>0` instead of a right-shift.

Comment: Next time, use more formatting and less question marks...

Comment: it's zero for me in Safari 5.0.3 (6533.19.4)

Comment: My Safari 5.0.2 on Mac gives 0.

Comment: `0` on Safari 5.0.3 (7533.19.4) on Windows 7

Comment: `0` in Safari 5.0.3 (6533.19.4) Mac OS X 10.6.5

Comment: StackOverflow is meant to stand alone. Although links to external resources (like jsFiddle) are great as an adjunct, always include the relevant code in your question as well. External links can move, get deleted, etc. I've done that for you in this case.

Answer (score 2):

> My thoughts are that the >> is being somehow interpreted as (>)>0 instead of a right-shift.

No, if it were tokenizing it like that, it would see a syntax error and you wouldn't get anything at all. *(And dozens of other things would break; the tokenizer **has** to be greedy on operators.)*

More likely it's an erroneous optimization (now fixed, apparently) seeing the `>> 0` as a no-op. I had to go double check [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) (Section 11.7.2 ["*The Signed Right Shift Operator ( >> )*"], page 76 of the 5th edition) to remind myself why it was coming out `0` as opposed to just the straight result of `Math.random()`. The key bit being, of course:

> The result is a signed 32-bit integer.

Talk about your edge cases...

Comment: Yeah, I abuse that edge case all the time to replace Math.floor() since it's about 20x faster.  I know, weird, but..


Anyway, The weird thing to me is that if you change almost anything about that code snippet, you get a result of 0.  Place a random float in there instead of "Math.random()" and it comes out to zero.  Assign Math.random() to a var and put it there, 0.  Remove the object literal, zero.  Change it to "<< 0", you get 0!


It's driving me crazy since I can't fathom what the actual bug is.  I know, doesn't matter, but still...

Comment: @Mark: Very weird! (Re 20x faster: Are you doing something where it actually matters? Don't get me wrong, I'm sure there's times when it does, but...)

Comment: sometimes, not often.  Just a habit I got into a while ago when I was doing something where it actually did -- tons of matrix math.  I started typing x>>0 instead of Math.floor(x) everywhere, it's also faster to type.  I'm pretty sure most of the speed increase comes from the functional call overhead, but every bit helps sometimes  :) The only catch before today was that it only works on numbers up to 2B (32-bit signed).  Guess I'm typing x<<0 from now on instead, since for some weird reason it doesn't trigger the same bug.